# WebDriver: I can't set path to IEDriverServer.exe that is in a Runnable Jar

Tags: java, path, resources, webdriver, executable-jar

.I have created a runnable Jar using Eclipse. The IEDriverServer.exe is present in the Jar. I am treating IEDriverServer.exe as a resource for the project.

The below line of code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Folder1/RunnableJar.jar/IEDriverServer.exe");
```

throws `Driver executable doesn't exist in the following path`.

I have put IEDriverServer.exe in the bin folder of the project. I am using the below line of code to get the path of IEDriver that is present in the bin folder.

```
MainClassName.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
                .getLocation().getPath() + "/IEDriverServer.exe";
```

If I am running the code from Eclipse then the path is the path to the IEDriverServer present in the bin folder. If I am exporting the project as a runnable Jar then the path is as shown below

> C:/Folder1/RunnableJar.jar/IEDriverServer.exe

If I am running it from the eclipse it works fine.

It throws the exception if I am running it as jar.

**I would like to know the way to set IEDriverServer.exe property from within the Runnable jar.**

Comment: Extract the Exe-File to a temporary directory and run it from there...

Comment: @AKDADEVIL Why do I need to extract the Jar? I just want to run it. And use the IEDriverServer.exe present in the Jar.

Comment: Fine, if you find a way to run an EXE-File directly from within a ZIP-File under Windows, be my guest and explain it here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run exe file directly from jar. You can only write a method that would be extract your exe to a temporary folder and then set your `System.setProperty` to that path value.

You can find some code example [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600146/run-exe-which-is-packaged-inside-jar)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to run exe directly from a Jar on Windows Platform.

As mentioned in one of the answers, the best way is to extract the exe from the jar to a temporary directory and set the property path to that directory.

The following links may help others with the same issue.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383536/including-an-exe-file-to-jar)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600146/run-exe-which-is-packaged-inside-jar)

[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134564/run-exe-packaged-in-jar)